# Parameterize column names in Redshift PL/pgSQL loop

Tags: sql, loops, amazon-redshift, parameter-passing, dynamic-sql

I need help on how to use SQL (or dynamic SQL) to code out a loop where I am using 'x' as a placeholder for column names. Anyone have any suggestion so I don't have to run this statement manually for every column?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PCI_COLUMNS()
AS $$
DECLARE
  x RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (select col from L_USA.COLUMNS WHERE TYPE = 'PCI')
    LOOP
        ATTACH MASKING POLICY COMMERCIAL_PCI
        ON L_USA.DEMO(x)
        USING (x, CUST_ID)
        TO ROLE COMM_PCI
        PRIORITY 30;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The above code is what I was envisioning but it spits out an error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "pci_columns" near line 5 [ErrorId: 1-6571f613-3df6ae50214fb89252a028fb])

because I don't think I can parameterize objects like this

Comment: @roganjosh, that is incorrect. See [Dynamic queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and [Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've had two passes at that first documentation and I cannot find where the column name is not hard-coded

Comment: "Expressions containing values that should be literal strings in the constructed command should be passed through quote_literal." Fair enough, TIL. I don't think there's a facility for this in python bindings but in raw postgres, it seems I'm wrong

Comment: Hate to do this again but you are mistaken. Not sure exactly what you mean by *Python bindings*, but: 1) `psycopg2` has [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) to generate SQL dynamically  2) `plpython` is well Python and you can build formatted strings as needed. In fact before `plpgsql` became more dynamic that is how I used to do it.

Comment: You've pasted an error that was caused by different code than what you're showing: there's not a single instance of `$1`. It makes little sense to guess what caused the error unless you show what you did exactly. Right now, neither your procedure, nor anything in it is parameterized. Also, the [DDM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_ddm.html) suggests this is Redshift, in PostgreSQL that'd be [RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html). There are similarities, but redshift has its own, separate tag on SO

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it's important to correct misinformation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL [`EXECUTE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html). Unfortunately, Redshift [doesn't](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) have [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) (it was [added in PostgreSQL 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.1.0/#AEN111125), some time after Redshift forked from PostgreSQL 8.0.2), so you need to [`quote_ident()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_QUOTE_IDENT.html) your column name before injecting it into the statement.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PCI_COLUMNS()
AS $$
DECLARE x RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (SELECT quote_ident(col) AS quoted_column 
              FROM L_USA.COLUMNS WHERE TYPE = 'PCI')
    LOOP EXECUTE 
        'ATTACH MASKING POLICY COMMERCIAL_PCI' ||
        'ON L_USA.DEMO('||x.quoted_column||')' ||
        'USING ('||x.quoted_column||', CUST_ID)' ||
        'TO ROLE COMM_PCI' ||
        'PRIORITY 30;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL PCI_COLUMNS();
```

Comment: how do I then go about executing this procedure to run the loop after the procedure is created?

Comment: [`CALL PCI_COLUMNS();`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CALL_procedure.html)

Comment: Does it require me to add parameters while calling the procedure? This is the error I keep getting: function concat("unknown", "unknown", character varying, "unknown", "unknown", character varying, "unknown", "unknown", "unknown") does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts. Where: SQL statement "SELECT CONCAT( 'ATTACH MASKING POLICY COMMERCIAL_PCI', 'ON L3_USCA.BMO_DEMO(', $1 ,')', 'USING (', $2 ,', CUST_ID)', 'TO ROLE COMMERCIAL_PCI', 'PRIORITY 30;')" PL/pgSQL function "pci_columns" line 5 at execute statement

Comment: That's an oversight on my part. PostgreSQL `concat()` is variadic, Redshift `concat()` is an exactly two-argument function. To work around this, you can instead chain [`||` operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_concat_op.html) - see the update.

Comment: it worked! thanks so much!